# List not appearing horizontally as expected

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've installed demo content for the theme "Kalium", which displays lists on the portfolio page as follows:

This is the demo list :

[image: demo list]

However, on my website the list instead display like such:

[image: website list]

If anyone could give some pointers that'd be great.

Cheers

Comment: show your code please

Comment: you can use `flex` or `inline` to `ul`/`li`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **flex:inline**, 
You can show example here 
 https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_inline-block_nav